# TWEEN.js TWEEN.update(time) not behaving as documented

Tags: javascript, tween.js

So, as I read it [here](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md#animating-with-tweenjs), TWEEN.update(#) should render the frame of the animation at # right? So if I run TWEEN.update(100) I should get the frame at 100 every time I run TWEEN.update(100).

The problem I'm having is that this update function seems to render 100 as being earlier and earlier every time I run it. So the frame animated at 100 the first time looks to be correct, but if I run it again it looks like its somewhere around frame 60, the next time it looks like its around 20 etc. until the animated element sits at the start of the tween and waits for a while with increasing length the longer I run the environment.

Has anybody else ran into this before? I'm using a variable that isn't directly tied to the passage of time IRL, so my animate function looks something like this:

```
animate(){
timeStep += variableControllingSpeed;
TWEEN.update(timeStep);
}
```

I've got UI that handles changing that speed variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, if you're manually setting the animation frames using .update(#), make sure to pass a parameter into your individual tween's .start() functions. Otherwise the elapsed variable of the tween goes negative.

In my case I am starting the tween's every time I switch which set of tweens I want running, so when you run that .start() function it'll either use the start value you pass or grab the window.performance.now(), so the longer it ran the bigger the gap between window.performance.now() and the value I was starting the tween chains at.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue!!